# How to implement a terminal emulator for windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, terminal, console-application, terminal-emulator

Here's a bit of C boilerplate for spawning and communicating with terminal programs on linux(and possibly other unixes)

```
int master, slave;

struct winsize wsize = {24, 80, 0, 0}; // 24 rows and 80 columns

if (openpty(&master, &slave, NULL, NULL, &wsize) < 0)
  die("Failed to open the pty master/slave");

if (!fork()) {
  // child, set session id and copy the pty slave to std{in,out,err}
  setsid();
  dup2(slave, STDIN_FILENO);
  dup2(slave, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(slave, STDERR_FILENO);
  close(master);
  close(slave);
  // then use one of the exec* variants to start executing the terminal program
}

// parent, close the pty slave
close(slave);
// At this point, we can read/write data from/to the master fd, and to the child
// process it would be the same as a user was interacting with the program
```

I understand that windows doesn't have `fork()` or `openpty()`, so my question is: How to achieve something similar on windows?

If possible, I would like to see the minimum amount of working C/C++ code required to do the following:

- Spawn an interactive session of cmd.exe using `CreateProcess`
- Obtain a set of handles/file descriptors that can be used to read/write data from/to the spawned process, in a way that would simulate a interactive console session.

Comment: I haven't found anything. I don't understand, how is this problem related with threads?

Comment: What is the functionality of `fork`? Can you use threads instead of a process?

Comment: No, fork is there to create a new process and then run the terminal program

Comment: I wouldn't call whats requested "implementing a terminal emulator".  PuTTY is a terminal emulator.   I'd say you're asking how to interact with a Windows console app.

Answer (score 0):

Windows console works very different from Linux console.  There's no PTY or virtual consoles in windows to spawn or connect to.  Your basically working in the windows console itself.

You would then handle all I/o your self to emulate a terminal, keeping track of the console as your window, x/y position coordinates, colors etc.

You can look into something like PDcurses for windows if you interested in text based interfaces.